# How to create animated view dynamically and keep other animated state in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I want to create a **Barrage** component for live videos:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Video />
      <BarrageLayer ref={r => this.barrageLayer = r} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

The `Barrage` can display multiple animating text from right to left, so it provide a function:

```js
onNewMessageReceive(msg) {
  this.barrageLayer.show(msg)
}
```

The animation is easy:

```
  render() {
    const marginLeft = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [width + 100, -width]
    })
    const { style } = this.props
    return (
      <View style={[s.container, style]}>
        <Animated.Text style={[s.color, { marginLeft }]}>TEST</Animated.Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Here comes the question: how to add new barrage which not break the old animation barrage?

I use `state` to save the barrage list but if the states change, the animation should restart, and if the barrage reach out of the screen, it should be removed from the state list.